# How to execute multiple select statement in one query in sqlite in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Is it possible to execute two or more select statement in one query in SQLite? For example,

We can execute create or insert query,

```
NSString *create_query = @"create table if not exists Employee (id integer primary key, firstName text, lastName text);create table if not exists Department (id integer primary key, department text, devision text)";
```

By using,

```
sqlite3_exec(self.contactDB,[create_query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) == SQLITE_OK)
```

we can execute it.

But if query is something like,

```
NSString *select_query = @"select * from Employee;select * from Department";
```

Then is it possible to execute? If yes then how to differentiate data from `sqlite3_step`?

Generally we are fetching data like,

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.contactDB, [select_query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"prepared from data get");

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *department = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSString *devision = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

        NSLog(@"Department : %@, Devision : %@",department,devision);
    }
    NSLog(@"errror1 is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(self.contactDB));
}
```

But if there is a two select statement then how to identify column and row in `sqlite3_step`?

We can execute two select statements together (i.e. select * from Employee;select * from Department ) in terminal, so it should some way in iOS I think.

Comment: Each statement should be in double quotes For ex; const char *sql_stmt = "select 1 .....;" "select 2.....;" ;

Comment: You can use `sqlite3_exec` and use the callback functions. Or if the column count/type were the same in the two queries, you could do a single `UNION` query. But why?

Comment: 1) Never use `select * from ...`. Always explicitly list out the columns you wish to select. 2) Why do you want to combine two `select` statements like this? They each return completely different values.

Comment: @rob : Yeah callback works. thanks...... :) And I have just asked for knowledge. I haven't requirement to do this.

Comment: @rmaddy : I have just asked for knowledge as i have confusion that if it is possible in terminal then it should possible in ios also.!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri : it is not mandatory yo use double quotes for each query or statement. You can use semicolon separated statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can perform this by using C style `callback` function with `sqlite3_exec`.

There is no proper code available on internet (I haven't found!) so i would like to answer with code sample.

We can implement `C - style callback` method like

```
int myCallback(void *parameter, int numberOfColumn, char **resultArr, char **column)
{

NSLog(@"number of column %d",numberOfColumn); // numberOfColumn is return total number of column for correspond table

NSString *columnName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:column[0]];  // This will return column name column[0] is for first, column[1] for second column etc
NSLog(@"column name is %@",columnName);

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:resultArr[2]]; // resultArr returns value for row with respactive column for correspond table. resultArr[2] considered as third column.

NSLog(@"result is %@",result);

return 0;
}
```

And we can call this callback function in our `sqlite3_exec` function like,

```
NSString *getData = @"select * from Department;select * from Employee";


if (sqlite3_exec(self.contactDB, [getData UTF8String], myCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), &err) == SQLITE_OK ) {


    if (err) {

        NSLog(@"error : %s",err);
    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"executed sucessfully");
    }

}
```

We have make bride : `(__bridge void *)(self)` as parameter of `sqlite3_exec`. We can pass `NULL` in this case because we have implemented c style function. But if we implement Objective - c style function or method then we must pass `(__bridge void *)(self)` as parameter.

So, By callback function we can execute multiple `queries` in one statement whether it is `select` type queries or else.

Reference : [One-Step Query Execution Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)

Comment: There is no reason to do this over performing two separate queries each with its own explicit list of columns. What is the perceived benefit of doing these two queries this way over the "normal" way?

Comment: Yep, there are numerous signifiant disadvantages of this approach, but there are edge cases where it can be useful.

Comment: Lion, by the way, you say "But if we implement Objective - c style function or method then we must pass `(__bridge void *)(self)` as parameter." I don't believe this is true. The callback always has to be the C-style function. But by passing `self`, that C-style function can at least now reference your `self` object and call its methods and/or access its properties.

Comment: @rmaddy : As i have said earlier i just want to check that is this any way. That's it. I am not recommending  anyone to use this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`sqlite3_exec()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) to execute two SELECT statements in one call. You just have to provide a callback function where you handle the result rows. I've never used that feature, and how I understand the doc you're on your own to distinguish the rows of each statement; perhaps one can use the column count for that.

I advise against using `sqlite3_exec()` that way; it seems rather tedious and error-prone. [`sqlite3_prepare_*()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) should be the way to go, and it can only handle one result set (SELECT query), but you can have open multiple statements at a time, represented by the `ppStmt` handle. If you have problems with that you should describe them instead of posting a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) question.

Comment: Yes, `sqlite3_exec()` and `callback` have made solution. You can check my answer to know how to implement it. And link was useful provided in answer...thanks for that.